# how to echo all tables that start with a prefix

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get all tables that start with a prefix

```php
   global $wpdb;
   $tables = $wpdb->get_results("show tables like 'pro_hist%'");
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($tables);
   echo '</pre>;
```

and this works, it gives me this answer

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Tables_in_plugin (pro_hist%)] => pro_hist1579
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Tables_in_plugin (pro_hist%)] => pro_hist1580
        )
)
```

but how can I echo this out?

if I do print_r($tables[0]) I get this result

```php
stdClass Object
(
    [Tables_in_plugin (pro_hist%)] => pro_hist1579
)
```

Now I wanted to echo "pro_hist1579" ?

Comment: Just iterate over the array with `foreach`. That's not a WordPress, is it?

Comment: yes, it is wp, $wpdb,  the thing is that [Tables_in_plugin (pro_hist%)] , I dont seem to be able to reach it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing the output type of `get_results()` to `ARRAY_A` or `ARRAY_N` and see what kind of array they give you.

E.g.

```
$tables = $wpdb->get_results("show tables like 'pro_hist%'", ARRAY_A);
var_dump($tables);
foreach( $tables as $table ) {
    var_dump($table);
}
```

If `$table` is an array and it has the name as the first value, then get the it for example with [`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

From the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/),

```
wpdb::get_results( string $query = null, string $output = OBJECT )
```

> $output
>
> (string) (Optional) Any of ARRAY_A | ARRAY_N | OBJECT | OBJECT_K
> constants. With one of the first three, return an array of rows
> indexed from 0 by SQL result row number. Each row is an associative
> array (column => value, ...), a numerically indexed array (0 => value,
> ...), or an object ( ->column = value ), respectively. With OBJECT_K,
> return an associative array of row objects keyed by the value of each
> row's first column's value. Duplicate keys are discarded.
>
> Default value: OBJECT

Comment: With ARRAY_N already gives me the correct value when inside the foreach I echo $table[0]. Thanks!.